# Add data to list based on a data frame R

Tags: r

I have the following list and data frame:

```
my_list <- list(names = c("JEFF","PETE","JOE"),
                data = c(1,2,3),
                ascor = c("ANCHOR","BOAT"))
my_df <- data.frame(names = c("JEFF","PETE","JOE"),
                    debt = c(10,12,14))
```

I would like to add a new element to the list called "debt" based on the data frame my_df. The new list should be (pardon me if I don't know how to express a list like a dataframe which shows as a table):

```
my_list <- list(names = c("JEFF","PETE","JOE"),
                data = c(1,2,3), 
                debt = c(10,12,14), 
                ascor = c("ANCHOR","BOAT"))
```

I tried naively this code:

```
my_list %>% left_join(my_df, by = "names" )
```

But it says is not applicable left join to an object list. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to `match` and create an entry

```
my_list[["debt"]] <- my_df$debt[match(my_list$name, my_df$names)]
```

---

Or with `modifyList`

```
modifyList(my_list, list(debt = my_df$debt[match(my_list$name, my_df$names)]))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. This sample reflects a geojson list, where I have some data which I wanted to match with a dataframe. I applied your first solution and worked fine.